# Using Where Clause in MVC Controller Created by Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, linq

I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model (Code First from database) to create models from an existing database, then I scaffolded controllers and views.  In my controller, I have:

```
' GET: Cities
Function Index() As ActionResult
    Return View(db.Cities.SortBy("CityName").ToList())
End Function
```

How can I pass a CountyID to the controller so I can list only the cities in one county?  If I were using a SQL query, I would write:

```
SELECT * FROM City WHERE CountyID = 1
```

I tried:

```
Function Index(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
    Return View(db.Cities.Where(db.Cities.CountyID.Equals(id)).SortBy("CityName").ToList())
End Function
```

But for "db.Cities.CountyID" it complains that "'CountyID' is not a member of 'DbSet(Of City)'"

I've found some examples that use lambda expressions, but I'm not entirely sure if I can even use those in VBScript.

```
Function Index(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
    Return View(db.Cities.Where(c >= c.CountyID = id).SortBy("CityName").ToList())
End Function
```

This gives me an error that "'c' is not declared"

I can't find any good examples of how to do this.  I'm new to MVC and apparently don't know enough to ask the right question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing VB.Net, not VBScript. Thats a huge difference and this also means that there are lambda expression :-)

It seems that you've found some C# samples before... 
The syntax for lambda expressions with VB.Net looks like this:

```
Function Index(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
    Return View(db.Cities.Where(Function(c) c.CountyID = id).OrderBy("CityName").ToList())
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks.  When I search, I find more things on C# than VB.Net.  I might end up learning both before I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Marc covers the correct lambda expression syntax for VB.NET, but you can also use the LINQ query syntax.  This is sometimes less typing, and may be more readable, depending on your personal preference (although there are some things that you can't do in the query syntax).

```
Function Index(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
    Return View((From c In db.Cities Where c.CountyID = id Order By c.CityName).ToList())
End Function
```